# Are there compatibility difference between dual-rank and single-rank memory modules?

Tags: memory

I have a laptop with a single stick of RAM, with one slot free. Here are the specs of the existing RAM stick: SODIMM DDR4 2400, Single Rank, None-Ecc.

I was thinking of the Crucial CT8G4SFS824A. Exactly the same specs as mine, and I used the compatibility checker on their website. It said that this would work.

My only question is, when I used the automatic check tool on the website, it recommended to me the dual-rank version of this same stick. After doing some research, apparently both DR and SR sticks are cross-compatible.

I just wanted to make sure before buying, because even though manually checking the single-rank stick with Crucial's utility said it was compatible, the tool recommended the dual-rank version.

Comment: You should re-word your title to be less of an open question. As it is, you may have the question put on hold for being too opinion based. I'd suggest getting at the heart of the question with the title... such as "Are there compatibility difference between dual-rank and single-rank memory modules?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep this objective... dual rank ram sticks can have a small performance increase compared to otherwise identical single rank ram sticks. Typically the price difference is minimal or non-existent. Both, however, should be entirely compatible.